# Using revtex4-2 with the biblatex package

Tags: bibliographies, document-classes, overleaf, revtex

I am struggling with LaTeX on Overleaf. I am trying to produce a bibliography and I can, however, only if I select the article class. If I switch to RevTex4-1, it still produces the output I want, but also 14 errors... preventing me to export the project. my code is:

```
\documentclass{article} %I do not want this one
%\documentclass[preprint,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-2} I want this one, but is does not work!

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,citestyle=nature]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{BIB_test.bib} %Imports bibliography file

\begin{document}

First cite this guy\cite{hallo}, next this one\cite{world}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

the bibfile is:

```
@article{hello,
author = {Cao, G. and McCall, S. and Crow, J. E. and Guertin, R. P.},
journal = {Physical Review Letters},
number = {9},
pages = {1751--1754},
title = {{Observation of a metallic antiferromagnetic phase and metal to nonmetal transition in Ca$_3$Ru$_2$O$_7$}},
volume = {78},
year = {1997}
}

@article{world,
author = {Alexander, C. S. and Cao, G. and Dobrosavljevic, V. and {Mc Call}, S. and Crow, J. E. and Lochner, E. and Guertin, R. P.},
doi = {10.1103/PhysRevB.60.R8422},
journal = {Phys. Rev. B},
number = {12},
pages = {R8422--R8425},
title = {{Destruction of the Mott insulating ground state of Ca$_2$RuO$_4$ by a structural transition}},
volume = {60},
year = {1999}
}
```

The main error I receive is that I should put \end{document} in the preamble. That cannot be true right?

Comment: Note that `revtex4-1` is marked obsolete, you should probably move to `revtex4-2` in any case. Also please provide a sample bib file such that others can easily test your code, and please cite the errors you get in overleaf. (you might want to mark your question with the `overleaf` tag)

Comment: Hi thanks for the comments. I added some information but I get 10 errors on overleaf. That might be too much for a forum?

Comment: revtex requires natbib and this is incompatible with biblatex. If you want to use biblatex you should use another class.

Comment: Hi there, Tom from Overleaf Support here. It's nothing to do with Overleaf in particular. As Ulrike says, `revtex` and `biblatex` are incompatible, that's the issue.

Comment: In the end I solved it by adding `\bibliographystyle{naturemag}` at the end of the code, which does work with Revtex. @yo' Tom, interestingly I had to start a new Overleaf project in order to have it work. My code is equal but starting a new code is a prerequisite. Again thanks for the help!

Comment: @RFermin Ah! Well, in that case, try to clear the project's cache (not the browser cache!) in the original project -- see https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache for details.