# Non-italic text in author name for Biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I am using this package in Overleaf for referencing for a Nature journal, but Nature journal requirement is that 'et al' shouldn't be in italics. Can please someone help me to solve this problem.

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=nature,citestyle=nature,backend=bibtex,style=nature,biblabel=brackets,giveninits=true,abbreviate=true,doi=false,eprint=true,url=false,isbn=false,block=space,natbib]{biblatex}
```

[image]

Comment: done, and thanks for solving the problem.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I think it would be useful if you could undelete your answer. Even if the code as posted above will error because of the incompatibility the answer is still useful for people who use `biblatex-nature` in a context where it does not error. (It may be useful to add a note in the answer that `biblatex` won't work with `revtex`, but that need not be the main focus.)

Comment: @moewe I added a note and undeleted.

Comment: @moewe I'm wondering if it might be good to roll-back the question into the pre-revtex state. I know I was the user who asked the OP to add the code which causes error, but in the pre-revtex state it would at least be useful for biblatex-nature users. In its current state, it is not really useful.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks. Upvoted. If you want a "reference" for the `revtex` incompatibility you could link to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12047/35864.

Comment: @moewe Thanks for the link!

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I think that makes sense. Rolled back to original state when `revtex` wasn't in the mix.

Comment: @moewe Your link might also be a good dupe-target for https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/575366/using-revtex4-2-with-the-biblatex-package (in case you want to use your gold hammer :) )

Comment: @AliBabar As mentioned `revtex` is incompatible with `biblatex` (see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12047/35864). If you need to use `revtex` you cannot use `biblatex` and should instead use the bibliography/citation facilities of the class.

Answer (score 2):

`biblatex-nature` enforces italics for "et al." in the bibmacro `name:andothers` ([`nature.bbx`, ll. 216-231 in v1.3d](https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-nature/blob/main/nature.bbx#L216-L231))

```
\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{%
  \ifboolexpr
    {
      test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
      and
      test \ifmorenames
    }
    {
      \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
        {\finalandcomma}
        {}%
      \andothersdelim
      \mkbibemph{\bibstring{andothers}}%
    }
    {}%
}
```

(This is slightly unidiomatic. `\mkbibemph{\bibstring{andothers}}` would more naturally be `\bibstring[\mkbibemph]{andothers}`. Or even better a wrapper command instead of bare `\mkbibemph`.)

If we want no italic `andothers` string across languages we will want to redefine this macro to get rid of the `\mkbibemph`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=nature,
]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{%
  \ifboolexpr
    {
      test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
      and
      test \ifmorenames
    }
    {
      \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
        {\finalandcomma}
        {}%
      \andothersdelim
      \bibstring{andothers}%
    }
    {}%
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \citeauthor{companion}
ipsum \textcite{aksin}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem Goossens et al. ipsum Aksın et al. [2]]

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{andothers = {\upshape et al\adddot}}
```

to format the `et al.` in whatever way you like (if you write in another language but English, adjust this accordingly).

Please note that I had to remove the `biblabel=brackets` from your code fragment to avoid it throwing an error.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  %bibstyle=nature,
  %citestyle=nature,
  backend=bibtex,
  style=nature,
  %biblabel=brackets,
  giveninits=true,
  abbreviate=true,
  doi=false,
  eprint=true,
  url=false,
  isbn=false,
  block=space,
  natbib
]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{andothers = {\upshape et al\adddot}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\citeauthor{companion}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: A solution that works across languages (but would be a bit longer code-wise) would be to redefine the `name:andothers` bibmacro, which has `\mkbibemph{\bibstring{andothers}}` to say just `\bibstring{andothers}` (https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-nature/blob/bbcc3d4f399e249de2689b0ddb048cdaa0fff354/nature.bbx#L228). (As an aside, `\mkbibemph{\bibstring{andothers}}` is a fairly unidiomatic `biblatex` code `\bibstring[\mkbibemph]{andothers}` would be more idiomatic.)

Comment: @moewe can you please post this as answer?